# Version information not displaying

Tags: c#, wmi

the following code doesnot shows the version information correctly.

```
     ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(new SelectQuery("Win32_Processor"));
        ManagementObjectCollection moc = mos.Get();
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
        {
Console.WriteLine("Version: " +mo["Version"].ToString());
}
```

it displays blank screen.

am using windows 7 version...

how to resolve it......?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this can help you:

[MSDN EnumerationOptions Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.enumerationoptions%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
        // Enumerate the Win32_Processor class
        EnumerationOptions opt = new EnumerationOptions();
        ManagementClass c = new ManagementClass("Win32_Processor");
        foreach (ManagementObject o in c.GetInstances(opt))
        {
            foreach (var item in o.Properties)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name + " " + item.Value);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yes, this code works and it used to get the system information.